# Little Tree Sappling

Tags: identification, trees

Does anyone know what this might be? It came up in the garden. It doesn't look like any other tree we have on our place.

[image]

Comment: Where are you located? It looks a little bit like a chestnut seedling, but I am not sure if that's correct.

Comment: What trees are in your little environment?  Take pictures of them...

Comment: b. nota, It does look like a chestnut seedling.  HOW COOL.  I hope it is.

Answer (score 2):

It's a red oak. There are seedlings just like this all over my yard, from the red oak in the back of it. If you were to pull it, you'd find a fairly small acorn attached to the stem. As newer leaves are formed, they'll begin to look like normal red oak leaves.